# Replace any combination of two char with second char only

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to replace any possible combination of underscore or comma with comma only.

For e.g.

```
,___, => ,
,,,,  => ,
_,    => ,
,_    => ,
_,_   => ,   //and so on
```

I searched for some answers. But all could find was things like "ways to replace any number of chars with a char".

```
x(?=y)  //I also tried using lookahead
(?<=y)x  //and lookbehind. But couldn't get it to work as intended.
```

What I am doing currently:

```
value = value.replace(/_/g, '');
value = value.replace(/,+(?=,)/g, '');
```

I know there must be a better one line solution. Thanks.

Comment: Note that your title and problem description are actually asking for two different things.

Comment: `,,,,` is not combination of `_ and ,`

Comment: oops, made changes to the question so that title and actual question align with each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try searching for the pattern `[,_]+` and then replace with just comma:

```js
var input = ",___,";
var output = input.replace(/[,_]+/g, ',');
console.log(output);
```

The quantity `[,_]+` is called a character class in regex lingo, and means one or more of any character contained within the square braces (in this case, comma or underscore).